# 正規表現で、ローマ字の大文字と半角スペースのみを有効な値としたい

Tags: 正規表現

クレジットカードの名前のところで、正規表現を使って入力値を制限しようとしていますが、うまくいかずにいます。

if (source.toString().matches("^[A-Z\s]+$".toRegex())
&& source.toString().matches("^[^\n]+$".toRegex())){

}

上記はうまくいくのですが、これを１つの正規表現で記述したいです。
※ "^[A-Z\s]+$" -> これだと改行が通る

Comment: \sを半角スペースに変えるだけではだめでしょうか。(必要なら\tも)

Comment: ご教授、ありがとうございました。
指摘の内容通りにしたところ、うまくいきました！

matches("^[A-Z ]+$".toRegex()

Answer (score 3):

`\s` は空白を意味し、TABやCR(行頭復帰)、LF(改行)が含まれます。
質問の内容を砕くと

- 先頭から末尾までが、AからZまでの文字もしくは空白にマッチ
- 先頭から末尾までが、改行文字でない文字にマッチ

ですのでコメント欄にもある通り、空白 `\s` をスペース  に変えてしまうのが手っ取り早いです。

ただし、このパターンには問題があり、おそらく `FOO BAR` といった物を期待されておられるかと思いますが、実はスペースが先頭や末尾に来てもマッチしてしまいます。それどころか全てスペースでもマッチします。

名前をマッチしたい場合は `^[A-Z][A-Z ]+[A-Z]` の様に先頭と末尾に必ず `[A-Z]` が入る事を確認した方がよいです。また空白が連続しない事も確認すべきです。
あと、氏名が1文字というのは考えにくいので他の条件も必要かと思います。

1文字でも良いのであれば、`^([A-Z]+)( [A-Z]+)*$` が良いかと思います。

Comment: ご教授、ありがとうございました。

Regex("^[A-Z][A-Z]+ [A-Z]+$")

これで、思った動きが実現できました。